# Delete a list of folders in temp

Tags: powershell

I want to delete a list of folders in temp.
Name of folders are numeric- **2, 3, 4 etc..**

```
PS C:\Users\sos$> Get-ChildItem -path C:\Temp
```

Is there a PowerShell way to get this scripted

Comment: You have seen `Get-ChildItem` you should look at `-Filter` or `Where-Object`. Have you looked at `Remove-Item`. You _really_ need to show some more effort for something like this. If you still have issues after that then please update your question.

Comment: $filename = 2
Get-childitem -path c:\temp | Where-object {$_.name -eq $filename} ----I can delete one file but I need to delete a list - If I use import-csv it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Soheil Hashemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3821841/soheil-hashemi) opened the bag on answering this question so lets have a look at a basic option.

You need to have all the files that are just a number from the temp directory. Let use `Where-Object` to match the files we are looking for.

```
$Path = "C:\temp"
Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -notmatch "\D"} | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Get all the files from the `$path` and match any files where the file name (without extension) only contains numbers. Then pipe the results into `Remove-Item`. Remove the `-WhatIf` when you are sure it is finding the right files.

If you don't have PowerShell 3.0 then you can change the `Where` clause and remove the `-Directory` switch.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object{$_.BaseName -notmatch "\D" -and $_.PSIsContainer} | Remove-Item -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
```

Comment: Maybe add the `-Directory` parameter to `Get-ChildItem` (PS v3.0+) or a `$_.IsPSContainer` clause to the `Where-Object` filter if only directories are to be removed

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes. The Op did say folders. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Thanks for the query it works fine. I tried to write the result to txt file - out-file C:\temp\logs.txt but it does not record any of the deleted folder. Also is there a way to skip the folders in use? Thanks Sam

Comment: Where possible please take the time to doing your own research on these two new and separate ideas you have. The system will not allow you to remove a folder in use so you might need to use a try/catch block to account for that.

Comment: I used -recurse and it skips the folder in use

Answer (score 0):

your question is not complete but first create list like me

```
$a = @'
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
'@
```

or `$a = (get-content c:\filelist.txt)`
then

```
$a | foreach { Remove-Item c:\temp\$_ }
```